# Jquery Show/Hide Toggle Next

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have multiple products on the page all being pulled in through database.
Under each I have a comment box that I want to show and hide by clicking the comment button.

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#product-box div#product-comment-box").hide();
    //$("#product-box div.comment").show();

$("#product-box div.comment").click(function(){
    $("li div#product-comment-box").toggle();
});
```

My HTML of a Product Area:

```
<li><div id="product-box">
    <div id="product-image"><a href="#"><img src="images/image_2.jpg"></a></div>
    <div id="product-controls">
        <a href="#"><div id="button" class="more"><p>More</p></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div id="button" class="add"><p>Add</p></div></a>
        <div id="button" class="comment"><p>Comment</p></div>
        <a href="#"><div id="button" class="like"><p>Like</p></div></a>
    </div>
    <p>Product Name</p>
    <div id="product-comment-box">Comment</div>
    </div></li>
```

**But this is managing to toggle all comment boxes on every product**, how do I separate these the best? I tried using next and nextAll, but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `this` to reference the current comment. Remember what the selector is doing, getting everything in DOM that matches.

```
$("#product-box div.comment").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('div#product-comment-box').toggle();
});
```

Although selecting by id does not seem like a good idea. Try giving that div a class and selecting by that instead.

```
//Change
<div id="product-comment-box">Comment</div>

//To
<div class="product-comment-box">Comment</div>  

//then select using class instead.
$("#product-box div.comment").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('div.product-comment-box').toggle();
});
```

Comment: How do i select the '#product-comment-box' from there? cheers

Comment: By using `$('selector', this)` you can limit the scope. Try my edited answer. Without your html I am only guessing though. I can't deduce your html structure from your selectors.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned above but no luck, would not operate. I added my HTML area above. Thanks heaps

Comment: Thanks for the html, makes it a lot clearer. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this way ... pass the id in divid like

```
              <div id="comment<?php echo "Your db id" ?>" class="show_to_public">

              </div>
              <div id="product-comment-box<?php echo "Your db id" ?>">

              </div>
```

so that you can seperate it in your jquery as..

```
      $('.show_to_public').click(function(e){   
        var id=$(this).attr("id").replace("comment","");
        $('#product-comment-box'+id).toggle();
      });
```

Comment: This is the way i usually do when i retrieve data in loop.hope this will surely helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Within the click handler, the `this` keyword refers to the element that you clicked.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

The handler parameter takes a callback function, as shown above. Within the handler, the keyword this refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound. To make use of the element in jQuery, it can be passed to the normal $() function. For example:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

You need to make use of that element to find the element you are looking for.  In your example, something like this would work:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.product-comment-box')
```

...almost.  Notice I have used a class called 'product-comment-box' instead of an ID.  That's because ID's are only for unique elements, and should never, ever be used on more than one element.  So you are also going to want to replace all your duplicate ID's with classes.  Simply replacing 'id' with 'class' should work in the snippet you used, except for the buttons, since they already have a class.  For those, you can just separate the classes by spaces:

```
<div class="button like">...
```

Comment: Just noticed that I have more or less duplicated what mrtsherman answered... Is there useful information here worth keeping, or should I just delete my answer?